# Why does this pattern emerge when randomly filling bins from a total pool of value?

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics

I wrote a small function to randomly generate a list of values which adds up to some total, in this case 100; written for some unrelated reason. After aggregating the lists and averaging across the indices I found that the averages displayed a pattern.

Here 1000 lists, of length 10, where the sum of all the values is 100, was generated and the average value for each index was calculated

$$l_1 = [50.35, 25.11, 12.33, 6.3, 2.92, 1.47, 0.75, 0.38, 0.18, 0.08]$$

The pattern I found is that the average value at a specific index is always approximately half of the last, and the first average is half of the total sum of the list.

For example here is a the same calculation on 1000 lists, of length 4, with a list sum of 50.

$$ l_2 = [24.774, 12.683, 6.265, 3.223] $$

For completeness here is a Python SSCCE which generates the lists and calculates the averages

```
import random

def genlist(len, total):
    r = []
    for i in range(0, len):
        if total == 0:
            r.append(0)
            continue
        v = random.randint(0, total)
        r.append(v)
        total -= v
    return r

list_of_lists = [genlist(4, 50) for i in range(0, 1000)]
transpose_lol = zip(*list_of_lists)
avg_index_value = [float(sum(x)) / len(x) for x in transpose_lol]

print(avg_index_value)
```

---

**Why does this pattern emerge?**

I can roughly see it, just based on how the "bins" that are the indices of the list are filled from a shrinking pool of total value. Though, saying that makes it seem as if the random value for the first index is always "large"; it is just as likely that it is small too. Thus, I keep reasoning back to myself that the average across the indices of the list should always just be `total/len`.

Comment: Two things: have a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers and check your implementation. Also, try it for a list length of 1. What do you expect and check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to the way you select the numbers. Your first sample is chosen uniformly from $[0,100]$, and the expected value is $50$. The second value is then chosen from $[0,50]$, which is most likely to be $25$, and so on. This explains the halving pattern you witness.

More formally, let $X_1 \sim \text{Unif}[0,1]$ and for each $n\geq 1$ let $X_{n+1} \sim \text{Unif}[0,X_n]$. Then you can prove $\Bbb E[X_{n+1}]=\frac{1}{2}\Bbb E[X_n]$, therefore by induction $E[X_n]=\frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n\geq 1$.

If you instead want numbers which are evenly dispersed throughout $[0,100]$, then here is one way. Take your desired number of samples from the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Let $S$ be the sum of your samples. Then divide every element by $S$, making your total sum to be exactly $1$ (this is called normalizing). Now multiply every element by $100$, and there you go, evenly dispersed numbers in $[0,100]$ which sum to $100$.

Comment: That makes total sense. Thank you.